# ps aux: zero VSZ

Tags: linux, ps

If I run `ps aux` on a RHEL7 box one of the columns has `VSZ` (virtual memory size) at the top. Why do many of the commands have a zero virtual memory size?

Answer (score 2):

They are likely kernel theads. Memory statistics are irrelevant with them as they use kernel memory.